# Why there isn't lower_bound and upper_bound for unordered_multimap?

Tags: c++, stl

Switching from a multimap to unordered_multimap, I realized there isn't the equivalent:

- lower_bound
- upper_bound

It seem obvious that the `equal_range` could make an easy equivalent, but I wonder if I am missing something: a reason for this choice.

Coming from any other library, I would have considered the difference a simple error, but STL is usually quite orthogonal in this respect.

Comment: how would those be of any use for an unsorted container?

Comment: btw not sure what you mean with "simple error" but in general a compile time error is much better than a runtime error

Comment: I though the lower_bound returns the first iterator with a given key, this could be possible on an unordered container. It seem I missed the case where the key is missing, where the order has importance.

Answer (score 10):

It's in the name. **unordered**_multimap. There is no order, and as such, no lower/upper relationship. Items (keys) stored in `unordred_*` containers are not even required to implement `<`/ `std::less`, only hash and equality operations.

Answer (score 4):

If you look into [`std::lower_bound()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`std::upper_bound()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) documentation, you can see that they have put a special requirement on the *range* they can be applied to:

> The range [first, last) must be partitioned with respect to the expression !(value < element) or !comp(value, element), i.e., all elements for which the expression is true must precede all elements for which the expression is false. A fully-sorted range meets this criterion.

As `std::map` satisfy that criterion one could use those generic functions on it, but such usage is not efficient, as those generic functions are unaware of the internal representation of the map. So `std::map` provided its own, more efficient variants (though less generic).  `std::unordered_map` on another side, does not satisfy the criterion so you cannot apply those generic functions on it and so it does not make any sense to implement them for `std::unorderd_map` itself.

> I though the lower_bound returns the first iterator with a given key, this could be possible on an unordered container.

This is what `std::find()` does. `std::lower_bound()` or `std::map::lower_bound()` gives you the position, from which elements of the range are not less than the key. The fact that you can use it to find a particular element is a useful side effect of that behavior, but not the main purpose of those functions.